# adb Terminal Command in Android Studio throws No Such File errors

Tags: android, terminal, android-emulator, adb

Someone smarter than me gave me an adb Terminal Command to push a file to a Android emulator, but I only get errors:
adb: error: cannot stat 'run-as': No such file or directory
adb: error: cannot stat 'com.parallelspaces.parkken': No such file or directory
adb: error: cannot stat '“OS_Catalina/Users/Tom_OS2/Android_Push/main.29.com.parallelspaces.parkken.obb”': No such file or directory.

There is a com.parallelspaces.parkken folder in the Emulator. I have checked and double checked the file and directory names, so I must be missing something more technical. Or plainly obvious.

To push the main.29.com.parallelspaces.parkken.obb file to the Emulator, this is the Command line:

sudo adb push run-as com.parallelspaces.parkken “OS_Catalina/Users/Tom_OS2/Android_Push/main.29.com.parallelspaces.parkken.obb” /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.parallelspaces.parkken

Any ideas would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` and `run-as` are completely out of place. This is the usage for `push`:

```
 push [--sync] [-z ALGORITHM] [-Z] LOCAL... REMOTE
     copy local files/directories to device
     --sync: only push files that are newer on the host than the device
     -n: dry run: push files to device without storing to the filesystem
     -z: enable compression with a specified algorithm (any/none/brotli/lz4/zstd)
     -Z: disable compression
```

so remove `run-as` and you don't need `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I removed the "run-as" and in a second try the whole "run-as com.parallelspaces.parkken" expression ( I am way out of my depth), but still get the now one Error:
"adb: error: cannot stat '“OS_Catalina/Users/Tom_OS2/Android_Push/main.29.com.parallelspaces.parkken.obb”': No such file or directory
- I swear on Father Xmas that file is in that folder and I have added this Folder to the Emulator and it is still there in Black and white.
Any further advice?

Comment: I doubt the path to your local file starts with `OS_Catalina` (relative path) but with `/Users/Tom_OS2/...`

Comment: Thanks again, but I have tried many variations of the path (including /Users) with no luck.
May I ask, what command would you use to send an ogg file from a Mac to an Android Emulator Folder called "com.parallelspaces.parkken" Then if it doesn't work I can think about reinstalling.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem before, and now it has been resolved.

The problem lies in the local file path after the push command. You can have two ways to modify it.

The first method is to replace the local file path with a relative file path.

The second option is to still use an absolute path for local files, but it is necessary to move the local files to another storage drive.